# Randomized Block ANOVA Model: Intermediate Steps

Tags: self-study, anova, variance

While reading through my lecture notes, I came across a randomized block ANOVA model and some assumptions. How did the authors get to these assumptions (Expectation and Variance) from the given model?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, those assumptions characterize the linear model $y_{ij} = \mu + \pi_i + \tau_j + \epsilon_{ij}$ i.e. the ANOVA setup[it is kind of linear regression with dummy variables].

You can see the result of a long-chain of assumptions in the $linearity$ of the variance(any basic statistics textbook would suffice for a reference) in the expression

$V(y_{ij}) = V(\mu + \pi_i + \tau_j + \epsilon_{ij}) = \sigma_{\pi}^2 + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2$

You would expect the covariances among each pair of $\mu$ , $\pi_i$ , $\tau_j$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$ to enter the equation too, however those are all $0$ which are the design assumptions in this case which are stated in your lecture. This means that the correlations among those are also zero.